# Find the half equivalence point

Tags: equilibrium, ph, titration

> How to find the half equivalence point knowing the pH, molarity, titrant added at equivalence point?

This a fairly straightforward and simple question, however I have found many different answers to this question. I originally thought that the half equivalence point was obtained by taking half the pH at the equivalence point. However, I have encountered some sources saying that it is obtained by halving the volume of the titrant added at equivalence point.

Comment: Yeah it's not half the pH at equivalence point your other sources are correct

Answer (score 1):

Half equivalence point is exactly what it sounds like. It is the point where the volume added is half of what it will be at the equivalence point.

There are 3 cases

1. **Strong Acid vs Strong Base:** Here one can simply apply *law of equivalence* and find amount of $\ce{H+}$ in the solution. Similar method for Strong base vs Strong Acid.
2. **Weak Acid vs Strong Base:** Here one can apply [Henderson-Hasselbalch equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation) as a general result one gets pH = pKa.
3. **Weak Base vs Strong Acid:** This case is similar to WA vs SB and one can easily use Henderson-Hasselbalch for bases again one gets pOH = pKb